# Why does the mongo shell work without mongod server being explicitly run?

Tags: mongodb, shell, nosql

Running MongoDB Shell v-3.2.8

I've noticed that articles and tutorials always mention to run the `mongod` server before running the `mongo` shell.

However, when I skip the first step and simply type `mongo` into my terminal, the mongo shell works without any errors / interruptions.

```
MacBook:Desktop user$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.8
connecting to: test
```

Why does this work? Does `mongo` call `mongod`?

Answer (score 4):

The `mongod` is being ran as a service or daemon, which means that there is always a `mongod` process running listening to a port. I use ubuntu, and when I install mongodb through the package manager, it immediately starts up a `mongod` process and begins listening on the standard port.

Running `mongo` is simply a small utility that attempts to connect to the localhost at the standard ip. The data reading, writing, and querying is done by the `mongod` process while `mongo` is a small program that sends the the commands to `mongod`.

If `mongod` wasn't running, you would see an error stating "Unable to connect to mongodb server"

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same. I think mongoose is doing some smart things there, which I'm not sure how it works. But I have noticed such things before, like mongoose will automatically add an "s" to your database's name when you declare it, which is a very thoughtful act =)).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same thing and found that in the background services if MongoDB server is running, the mongo shell will work without any error. If we stop the service, the shell will throw an error.

Comment: The mongo shell is a standalone client application it does not need any mongo server instance to run.  If you run the mongo shell with no parameters it will default to the locally running mongo server.  In your scenario if you stopped the service, there is no locally running mongo server and thus nothing to connect to so the shell would throw the error.